# How I get a Set<Object> using QueryDSL?

Tags: hibernate, annotations, set, querydsl

I have an Person entity mapped here, inside this entity I have a set of roles (Set roles) mapped with JPA Annotations, ok... Well, I can't get the set of roles from this commmand using QueryDSL:

```
Set<Role> roles = query.from(qPerson).where(qPerson.login.eq(userName)).uniqueResult(qPessoa.roles);
```

Is that possible? What do you suggest? Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by JPA, but you can use the following form

```
query.from(qPerson).innerJoin(qPerson.roles, qRole)
  .where(qPerson.login.eq(userName))
  .list(qRole);
```

Comment: I got here now but I think that this way is better. I'll try, thanks!
I got that:

Object roles = query.from(qPerson).where(qPerson.login.eq(userName)).list(qPerson.roles);
if (roles != null && (roles instanceOf List)) {
List<Role> rolesList = (List<Role>) roles;
Set<Role> rolesSet = new HashSet<Role>();
for (Role role : rolesList){
rolesSet.add(role);
}
}
And so on...

Comment: That looks like a weird hack. Why are you unsure about the type of the result?

Comment: I took a look at querydsl code and realized that queryDSL return a ArrayList of Objects, only then later converts. Then, as I'm sure of the type, I decided to do it this way. I don't consider a weird hack for what I need, but a great hack, because just did a conversion types and solved my problem. (sorry for my english)

Comment: It works, I just don't want it to be adopted on a wider scale.